# How to solve Ajax IM PDO Exception error in Go Daddy server?

Tags: php, pdo

I tried to install ajaxim in godaddy hosting server windows hosting account and when I clicked "install" it says:

> error:
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'couldn't find driver  in /.../install.php:332 Stack trace:
>
> #0 /.../install.php(332): PDO->__construct('mysql:dbname=rm...', '*rm*', '*Co123*')
>
> #1 {main} thrown in /.../install.php on line 332

I have no rights  to edit php.ini in godaddy, so how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

PHP support is being phased out of AJAX IM. I actually work with the guy that created it; he's converting the platform exclusively to run on Node.js. In order to take advantage of this, you will need to upgrade your GoDaddy account to a *nix VPS solution and install Node.js.

I'm talking to the developer right now: GoDaddy doesn't have access to PDO, so you cannot run AJAX IM on their shared hosting platforms. A better solution would be to use a VPS platform like Linode, which is fully supported.

So to sum things up:

- The PHP parts of AJAX IM are no longer supported by the developer and likely won't work.
- GoDaddy shared hosting isn't compatible with AJAX IM anyway.